# Conferences on “Technology Foresight”

Tags: conference

I am working on research in the field of renewable energy and technology transfer. The research methodology that I have applied in my study is called the “Technology Foresight”, where I am using methodologies such as STEEPV analysis, Delphi surveys and scenario building and so on. My question is with relevant to the conferences. With the literature survey that I did at the initial stage of my studies I came up with a technology Foresight model that can be applied to my study. This is sort of a unique model which my supervisors suggest me to publish it in a conference. The reason they asked me to do so, is to network with other research community who are very much familiar with this methodology “Technology Foresight”.

But I have no idea as how to find good conferences which consider “technology Foresight” as one of their main them. My supervisors are also not that familiar with this methodology as they are from the renewable energy and technology transfer fields. I would really appreciate if you can suggest me good conferences in the field of “Technology Foresight”.

Comment: Where are you studying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't have done your work in isolation: so you've already built up a list of references that you're working from. From this list, pull out the top ten that are most pertinent to technology foresight.  If necessary, supplement this with a quick literature search in the usual places for papers in technology foresight in other areas.

From that list of papers, take the list of authors. Now, look at the web pages for each of the authors - they'll mostly, if not all, have a page of publications. You're looking for the section on conference papers.

Make a note of the conferences that they've presented technology foresight work at. You're looking for those conferences which keep cropping up on the pages of your authors of interest.

This should build up a picture of where the key players present at.

Just be careful with "futurology" conferences - they can be a real mixed bag. Some lack rigour, don't report on the development of protocols and methods, and lack other academic qualities. And thus they will bring you no useful networking, nor constructive feedback.

You might find some of the energy-systems modelling conferences useful too, as they can have sections devoted to scenario development, which will overlap a fair bit with technology foresight - but don't invest too much effort there, because it's a bit of a stretch, unles your own work overlaps a lot with energy-systems models. FWIW, my opinion is that you shouldn't spend too much time looking at the International Energy Agency (IEA): they've been behind the curve for decades, and that's not changing yet.

[The International Renewable Energy Agency (IRENA)](http://irena.org/) have been looking a bit at foresight and technology transfer: they're a very young and growing organisation, so there might or might not be something useful there, but do keep an eye on them.

And the [UK Energy Research Centre (UKERC)](http://www.ukerc.ac.uk/support/NERNevents) maintains a list of international energy conferences that you might find useful.

On the technology transfer aspect, I guess development conferences might be where it's at, but that's a lot further from my own area, so that's just wild speculation on my part.

<sub>Disclosure: I'm not directly affiliated with any of those organisations, but friends and colleagues are.</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much on your respond. As you suggested conference papers published by the authors of key literature on Technology Foresight is a good suggestion. I do really appreciate your valuable information on IRENA and UKERC.

Comment: Presently I am based in Sri Lanka and my research is on technology transfer in the renewable energy sector of Sri Lanka. As a developing nation the amount of fund that is been allocated to academic purposes are very limited and my budget is very tight on this matter. Thus I am actually looking for a good conference that is taking place in the Asian region. So I would really appreciate if you could suggest any conferences that you are familiar with this regards. Thank You!